# need help troubleshooting periodic site slowness on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, pagespeed

I have a report from my client about intermittent IE slowness of their site. Whenever I check it on IE it is fine (native IE on windows on a PC and via VMWare). My designer can replicate the problem, but of course I can't see it! The site is periodically slow on IE (not always). The site is on a CMS (Expression Engine), fwiw, and we've taken the front-end code and moved it to a different server and haven't seen any slowness. Here's the kicker. When the site *is* slow in IE for people who can see it, it *isn't* slow in other browsers. ***only ever*** IE. I can't get my brain around how this is possible. Ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

The site does make use of db, image and template caching, which doesn't seem to have affected this problem...

I should mention that the page is using the cycle plugin for jquery and tooltip as well. perhaps those? there's no js error and they work just fine... just an idea

Comment: The key to troubleshooting this kind of problem is replication. You need to replicate the client's version of IE, installed toolbars, operating system environment, network connection, and possibly room humidity. In all seriousness though, If the slowness is only exhibited on one machine, you probably don't have anything to worry about. If you have a host of machines that *reliably* have this problem you should be able to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

I know that when I use IE at work (ver. 6, 7 & 8) that after several hours of work, either opening new tabs, new windows, closing tabs, closing windows.... whatever... day to day browsing if you will...

That I end up with multiple instances of iexplore.exe in my task manager, and one of those instances is just gobbling up my memory... in some cases I have seen the memory usage at over 200,000Kb... and not only slowing down IE, but the entire system...

Maybe have see that when they experience this if they see multiple instanced of iexplore.exe open and see what the mem usage is.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to replicate at least see if you can get the time of the occurrence. You can then check the websever logs for the time and IP and see if you see anything amiss .

Your designer should be able to help you here . Have that person call you when the problem occurs so you can check the servers.

It also important to know which version of IE . If users having the problems are using 6 or 7 then I would expend much less effort then 8 or 9 .